# Pre-ANSI C with no-arg prototypes and 64-bit architecture in VS2010, second and third arguments disappear

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, function-prototypes

I know this is weird, but here goes.

I'm managing a very old pre-ANSI C code base. The following code, believe it or not, actually compiles.

**myprog.c**:

```
// Prototype.
int rec_index();                                           // Zero arguments.

kz = rec_index(1, 19, 2, 0, "  ", 0, -1);                  // Seven arguments.
```

**recindex.c**:

```
int rec_index(flag, type, from, to, c, s, status, t)       // Eight arguments.
    int flag, type, from, to, s, status, t;
    char *c;
{ 
    printf("%d %d %d", flag, type, from);

    if (flag < 0 || flag > 2) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (type < 1 || type > 20) {         // Line A.
        return -1;
    }

    if ((flag == 1) && (type < 7 || type == 12 || type == 13)) {     // Line B.
        // Line C.
    }
}
```

In a 32-bit environment, this behaves reasonably well. The missing argument `t` in the function definition is interpreted to be zero (or maybe more properly, it's undefined), but that's only included in a small subset of calls to this function and the long-gone developers knew to include that when it was needed. So, when running this code, the output would be the first three parameters, as expected:

```
1 19 2
```

Great. The method returns with the expected behavior.

However...

We recently began porting our software to a 64-bit environment. In a 64-bit configuration, regardless of what is passed into the function, **the second and third parameters of eight are read as zero in the function**.

So, pass in 1, 19, and 2 in the function call, and inspect the parameters inside the function, and Visual Studio reports them as 1, 0, and 0.

```
1 0 0
```

Oddly, the fourth through eighth parameters pass through correctly. Only the second and third are wrong.

This is like standing next to someone, taking an empty wallet, inserting $3, handing them the wallet, and them opening it to find it empty. Where did the values go?

But it gets stranger. I passed in `type` as 19, but the function is reporting that its value is zero. (This is backed up by inspecting the memory location `&type`.) Let's just go with that for a second.

Now we get to the `if` statement marked as Line A in recindex.c:

```
    if (type < 1 || type > 20) {         // Line A.
```

Since `type` is being reported to be zero by the debugger, the left side of the `||` should be true and this will short-circuit the whole boolean to true, jumping into the braces and resulting in `return -1;`. Oddly, this does **NOT** happen, and the debugger jumps to the next `if` at Line B:

```
    if ((flag == 1) && (type < 7 || type == 12 || type == 13)) {     // Line B.
```

Again, `type` should be zero, and `flag` is (actually left untouched) as 1. This should make the whole `if` condition true, and fall into the loop to Line C.

The instruction pointer jumps into the loop as expected, but the value of `type` changes from 0 to some large value, always different, around 5000000 or so. **NOTHING in the `if` condition has any side effects, so how is this value changing?!**

I'd guess that there's some kind of stack corruption going on, probably as a result of undefined behavior due to the very inconsistent function prototyping. Again, this actually **works** in a 32-bit environment, and has for 20+ years.

The right answer here is to rewrite the function calls so as to all take eight arguments, matching the function declaration, and to use types like `int32_t` instead of `int` so that we can be sure of sizing. I'll likely do that.

However, I'd love an explanation of why I'm seeing the behavior I am.

- Why are the second and third arguments to the function being re-written as zero once the function is entered?
- Why is the value of one of those arguments, although appearing to be zero, isn't behaving like zero when evaluated?
- What is causing that value to change when there is nothing to change it?

Comment: When you say that *"Visual Studio reports them as 1, 0, and 0."*, are you looking at them in the IDE with the Watch window, or via the `printf` statement?

Comment: Actually in the watches. The `printf` here is just to show what would occur.

Comment: In that case, I think it is likely that the debugger is confused. (debuggers aren't perfect!).  I suspect the proper values of 1, 19, 2 are actually there (as suggested by the program flow through the if-statements).

Comment: Possibly. I would have expected the `if` at Line A to evaluate to true for real and return, rather than continue on. When turning on the memory view in Visual Studio, the value of the second parameter is also updated (erroneously).

Comment: If you just write a proper prototype for the function, then compile it all with modern compiler (like VS) you should be fine. No need to worry about how big the ints are, just make sure they're declared properly.

Comment: Have you recompiled both files in the 64-bit environment?

Comment: @LenchoReyes: Absolutely, and I think that's the eventual real fix. I'm wondering though if there's a reason for the behavior I'm seeing. And yes, I've rebuilt each time I've changed configurations. I'm quite sure these are the proper files.

Comment: I wrote a lot of pre-ANSI C code in my time, and some of it was during transitions from 16-bit integers to 32-bit integers, which I'm going to assume exposes many of the same issues as 32-bit to 64-bit. Your code looks fine and should work, albeit ugly in this day and age. I believe you're saying it works, but looking at in the Visual Studio debugger shows weird things.

Comment: My guess is that a combination of optimizations and the debugger just doesn't quite work right with pre-ANSI code -- understandable, as it probably doesn't get tested that much. If you're really keen to figure this out, try compiling with all optimizations turned off and see if it behaves better -- Sorry, I don't know Visual Studio so I can't tell you off the top of my head how to turn off the optimizations.

Comment: Thanks, @LenchoReyes! I'll post here if I ever get a real answer as to why this is exhibiting the strange behavior it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

I mentioned (with a bit of obfuscation) that I was calling this function:

```
int rec_index(flag, type, from, to, ck, sec, status, tert)
    int flag, type, from, to, sec, status, tert;
    char *ck;
{ … }
```

In the post I'd written that the call to this function was as such:

```
  kz = rec_index(1, 19, 2, 0, "  ", 0, -1);                  // Seven arguments.
```

But to not avoid sharing too many internal snippets on a public internet forum, I had actually paraphrased this, the real code:

```
kz = rec_index(1, 19, trp->iztabl, 0, "  ", 0, -1);
```

I was assuming that the inconsistent prototypes were causing the corruption. Of course not – the real problem is with that third parameter, `trp->iztabl`. The variable `trp` is of type `struct tran *`, a pointer to a struct. Upon introspecting the actual value and attempting to dereference this, I found that `trp` was a bad pointer. Not a NULL pointer, but a BAD pointer – just gibberish, pointing to an unknown region of memory.

When the object code hits a bad pointer, it either doesn't know how to use the arrow operator, or more likely, it goes to the appropriate place in memory specified by `trp` and jumps forward a number of bytes corresponding to `iztabl`'s location in the struct. Still, one would expect this should just return gibberish.

The problem/compiler bug/general annoyance is that the value returned by the failed application of the arrow operator is a 64-bit pointer, since we're in a 64-bit environment, and not a 32-bit int as `trp->iztabl` is defined. Since the call to `rec_index()` consists of 32-bit integers next to each other, the act of inserting a 64-bit pointer is destructive. This is why the second and third arguments disappear. The returned value of `trp->iztabl` takes out its own memory location and the one BEFORE it (due to endianness).

The other behavior I saw was related to values being overwritten in the debugger. I suspect the debugger's expected behavior is different than what this code provided, and so it got confused as it ran.